# Find the path of the source code for the executable being currently debugged in GDB

Tags: gdb

I can set a breakpoint in main and debug the code with the correct source code, but I don't know where GDB is taking the source code from.

The source code is not present in [CWD](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Working-Directory.html) (current working directory).

How do I find from which location GDB is taking the code?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use the GDB command:

```
info source
```

Sample output:

```
Current source file is a.c
Compilation directory is /home/user/test
Located in /home/user/test/a.c
Contains 17 lines.
Source language is c.
Compiled with DWARF 2 debugging format.
Includes preprocessor macro info.
```

Comment: where do the gdb stores this source code location? Is it in the executable itself?

Comment: In executable itself that was built with debugging information.

Comment: If GDB already stores the information in executable, why it needs source again?

Comment: Directories could be moved between the compilation and a debugging session

Comment: @ernesto I think it only stores a instruction to line number map (line table), not the actual source code. For example, `strings a.out` does not show the source.

Comment: GDB command `info sources` can be used to get the source files list used to compile the executable.
Please note the extra s to the sources.

Answer (score 6):

Use

```
(gdb) show directories
```

If you don't know where those directories are set, check your **.gdbinit** file to see if there are statements like

```
directory /path/to/source
```

See also [this other Stack Overflow question about GDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103161/gdb-searching-for-source-directories).

Answer (score 6):

This information is kept in the binary in the [DWARF2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) format. So, in order to see the DWARF2 information, you can use the dwarfdump utility. Needed information is kept in the DW_AT_comp_dir field.

Answer (score 3):

The binary is probably compiled with "-g" - i.e. debugging.

Comment: That does not mean the source is compiled into the binary.

Comment: But it does mean that references to the original source are kept. I've tried this on my system and it works.

Answer (score 2):

Use the GDB "show directories" command to see the source search path.