# command to detect the default debugging format

Tags: debugging, gcc, format, default

I was wondering if anyone knows how to read the default debugging format for a given platform.

If you want to help me further, here is the big picture. I'm having problems with gcc storing the full path of some source files in a library(gsl) in xubuntu 11.10 but not doing so in a rocks cluster with redhat. xubuntu has gcc 4.6 and and red hat has 4.1; the redhat cluster is x64 and the xubuntu is x32. These are the differences that I know of. The problem is that gdb finds the source files in ubuntu but not in redhat; in redhat, only the source file names are stored (info sources), without the path. The really strange thing (IMO) is that the code and makefiles are the same in both platforms, the only difference are the paths (which are absolute in both).

So at this point my only clue is that somehow the debugging format by default is not stabs in both platforms. So I wanted to check those in each platform. But if you can give me a hand with the overall problem, I'd appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the [dwarfdump](http://wiki.dwarfstd.org/index.php?title=Libdwarf_And_Dwarfdump) utility to get additional info about the debugging info in the binaries on the different platforms.

I'd be surprised if the debugging format was stabs on either platform unless you had explicitly requested it with `-gstabs` as an argument to gcc. I'm pretty sure that DWARF has been the default for linux intel gcc for a long time. You could check by using `readelf -S <binary>` to look for a .stab or .stabstr section to see if it is really using stabs.

Comment: Hi, first of all thanks for your help. I tried compiling with -g and -gstabs+ and as you suggested, the gstabs+ version had the .stab and .stabstr sections. The plain -g ones didn't have those in either platform, so I'll assume `DWARF` on both. Using the tool you suggested which I didn't know of (readelf), I notice that the only entry that is different between  the two binaries is `.note.gnu.build-i` of type `NOTE` present in the xubuntu version. Could that be relevant? Do you have any suggestions on how to try and get those absolute paths in the debugging binary in redhat?

Comment: I am not the admin of the cluster, so I can't try dwarfdump cause it's not installed. The admin already installed gdb for me, so I can't really push it too much further in that direction...

Comment: Well, you could always compile dwarfdump and libdwarf from sources, they have instructions at the link I provided earlier. I really don't have any great additional ideas about why the binaries are different. However, perhaps you can sidestep this whole issue by using gdb's 'directory' command to tell gdb where to look for the sources on the install where the paths aren't recorded in the debug info.

Comment: yes, that is what I'm doing so far. The main issue is that gsl has tens of subdirectories. So I have to manually provide a lot of them. I was considering making a script that will build a list of subdirectories and produce a .gdbinit file; the thing is that given my programming and bash skills, that is kind of a project in its own right for me. I will try dwarfdump from source, I didn't think it could work without any root access, but giving it a try won't hurt... thanks again for your suggestions;

Comment: I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103161/gdb-searching-for-source-directories