# set substitute path in GDB

Tags: debugging, gdb

I want to use gdb to debug my application which also links to some libraries. I also have the source code to the libraries. When I try to step into a function it complains that it cannot find the file, understandably since gdb does not know where to look.

I have googled and found two ways of doing:

- *Set directories*. However, this is not of much help since the source code for the actual libraries has hundreds of directories. Is there a way to recursively set directories.
- *set substitute-path from to*. This looks promising but I do not know what is the "from". I also could not find a way to print out the "cdir" which I assume is the "from" I am looking for.

Is there any other way for traversing through source code which has been moved.

For example :

> Original source code: /unknown_location
>
> Source code current location : /home/my_local_machine
>
> My executable : /home/my_application

When running gdb:

I get an error like this:

> Cannot find XYZ file

So I want to do something like this:

> set substitute-path /unknown_location /home/my_local_machine

OR

> set directories /home/my_local_machine (should be recursive)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: @Olaf This is a question about how to use gdb rather than "why isn't this code working". I want to figure out how to setup gdb to look for correct directories. I don't know how I can give an example for the same.

Comment: Did yopu even read [ask]? You very well ask what I wrote. And as you don't provide the required information, your question is subject to be closed.

Comment: I found a solution tho this problem here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103161/gdb-searching-for-source-directories
It uses the -d option for gdb