# gdb source path substitution to path containing $HOME or ~

Tags: debugging, gdb

I know from [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1327343/445241) that one can change the source paths in gdb, e.g. `(gdb) set substitute-path /usr/src/include /mnt/include`

However, say the destination path is `~/source`, am I able to make the path include a `~` or `$HOME`? e.g. `"$HOME"/source` or `~/source`? The source files couldn't seem to be found after being set to any of these options.

Right now it seems I have to put `/home/<username>/source` but I was hoping to automate this across systems with different usernames.

Comment: Adding on, I know I can use `(gdb) show env HOME` to get this in gdb, but how would I use this result in the `set substitute-path` command above?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't check, but suspect that `substitute-path` treats the "from" and "to" arguments as string literals with no expansion.

You can of course achieve desired effect with a shell wrapper:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec gdb -ex "set substitute-path /usr/src/include $HOME/source" "$@"
```