# Eclipse is not able to find sources during debug

Tags: eclipse, debugging, gdb, elf, debug-information

I'm building my c/c++ application for arm controllers with gcc in a docker. There together with the .hex and .bin file also the .elf file is generated. Once generated they all are exported out from the container to the host machine. Now I would like to debug the application with openocd, arm-none-eabi-gdb and eclipse cdt. I'm able to start debug session on the target board, but when I stop the debugger (or it stops on its on at startup on main) it is not able to find the source files to show:

```
Can't find a source file at "/usr/src/Testbench/LIBS/Shell/shell.c"
```

The path here is the one of the build project in the docker container and has nothing to do with the new debug project on the host where all files are located now.
I tried to edit source lookup path in eclipse with no luck, I could find the file an then it worked for just that file. Also specifying the folders did not work. Anyway, doing it manually always for all files/folders in the project is not an option.

The solution should be "scripted" since all this is part of a CI/devops concept.

It seems that the "wrong" path is hard coded in the elf file. Is there a (scripted) way to change that path to match the actual project location so that eclipse and gdb just work as expected and the developper can see the debug info when debugging?

Possibly it should work on Linux and Windows ;-)

Thanks in advance for your help

Martin

Comment: For gdb, see the question [gdb searching for source directories](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1327343/2554472)

Comment: Hi @MarkPlotnick Thanks for your answer, I did that and gdb accepted the command with no errors but when I then start the debug process again it still shows the same wrong path error. Do I need to pass this command to gdb when I launch the debug jop? If so, maybe you know how that is done in Eclipse?

Comment: You can put gdb commands in `.gdbinit` in your home directory and they'll be run every time gdb is started. You can also have gdb execute a single command by starting gdb with the `-ex "command"` option. I don't know how to make Eclipse look for source files in a place that differs from the path in the executable.

Comment: Hi @MarkPlotnick, I added the flag "set substitute-path /usr/src/ /home/martin/C_Projects/" and if I put a little typo in it the error shows the correct path to the source except the typo. If I fix the typo the following error appears: 
No source available for "(gdb[1].proc[42000].threadGroup[i1],gdb[1].proc[42000].OSthread[1]).thread[1].frame[0]"

Comment: so the (gdb[1] ... error has gone and I can change the path as described above. But whatever path I insert is wrong, even the absolutely correct absolute path is not working, or the relative path to the project or workspace is not working. Running out of Ideas :-(

Answer (score 0):

Now it works! In eclipse in the debug configuration in the gdb commands I added :

```
set substitute-path /usr/src/ ${workspace_loc}
```

Then I had to go to the source lookup path in eclipse and remove everything.